# Changing the Font and font Size in a textarea field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using the following code sample:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language = "Javascript">

maxL=240;
var bName = navigator.appName;
function taLimit(taObj) {
 if (taObj.value.length==maxL) return false;
 return true;
}

function taCount(taObj,Cnt) { 
 objCnt=createObject(Cnt);
 objVal=taObj.value;
 if (objVal.length>maxL) objVal=objVal.substring(0,maxL);
 if (objCnt) {
  if(bName == "Netscape"){ 
   objCnt.textContent=maxL-objVal.length;}
  else{objCnt.innerText=maxL-objVal.length;}
 }
 return true;
}
function createObject(objId) {
 if (document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(objId);
 else if (document.layers) return eval("document." + objId);
 else if (document.all) return eval("document.all." + objId);
 else return eval("document." + objId);
}
</script>
<font face="Arial" font size="2">
Maximum Number of characters for this text box is 240.</font><br>

<textarea onKeyPress="return taLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return taCount(this,'myCounter')" name="Message" rows=6 wrap="physical" cols=42>
</textarea>
<br>
<font face="Arial" font size="2">
You have <B><SPAN id=myCounter>240</SPAN></B> characters remaining 
for your message</font>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I change the font and font size in the textarea?

Comment: My advice would be to find a more recent code fragment to use. Use of the `<font>` tag et al. has been deprecated for ages. Also, checking for Netscape is not really required anymore either... could you tell us what exactly you want to do, maybe someone can get you some modern code to do it ;)

Comment: Not to mention using the `language` attribute on `script` tags... And then there's the implicit global variable. OMG, and the `eval` s. Yeah, this code has slipped through a time machine from 1998. Strongly recommend looking for something more recent.

Comment: @Spiny Norman: I think QA is new to HTML and he is reading kind of an old HTML tutorial.

Comment: @Fred: Apologies if Spiny and I have the wrong end of the stick. We've assumed you've grabbed or inherited this code from somewhere, not written it yourself. If the latter, it would be easy to be offended by our comments. Apologies if so, not how they were meant.

Comment: @Time Machine Yeah, I'm trying to find a nice piece of code to impose a character limit that is no more than a year old, but I can't find anything with no jQuery in it ;)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, @Fred Same here! We're all here to learn and have a good time, and all that.

Answer (score 20):

Use [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) to define a style for the `textarea` element. For example:

```
textarea {
   font-size: 20pt;
   font-family: Arial;
}
```

Note that there are [three ways](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) to add CSS to your website -- you can use an external stylesheet, an internal stylesheet, or inline styles (or a combination thereof).

Using an internal stylesheet might look like this:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
   font-size: 20pt;
   font-family: Arial;
} 
</style>
</head>

<!-- rest of your code goes here... -->
```

See [here](http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-nice-textarea/) for more information on styling `textarea`.

Comment: @mingos depends on the original size. If this original size were 0.0000000000000001pt you are right. ^^

Comment: You're right; this was more of just a quick example. Didn't think through the size too much :P

Comment: pt is for points, it is only recommended that you use this when you are going to do something in print. (so posters,business cards, invitations etc...).. Otherwise it's not for web.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but I am sure someone could use this information:

use Iframe and initialize it to run when the page is loaded and hide textarea...this helps if you want to make a WYSIWYG editor.

html page:
onLoad="iFrame()"

js page: 
    function iFrame(){
  name.document.designMode = 'on';
  name.document.execCommand('fontName',false,"verdana");

}