# Auto minimising text in textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a textarea where the user inputs there data, but as they add it when the cursor gets to the end it reduces the size of the font. All works quite well but I cannot seem to set a limit on how small it goes. Also is there any way I can set the point at which the text starts to go small, because the text tends to disappear at the end before shrinking? Please could someone help with this, seem to be pulling my hair out on this one?

```
function textAreaChange(){
    var textArea1 = document.getElementById("textarea");
    var sizeText1 = document.getElementById("size_text");

    while (textArea1.scrollWidth > textArea1.clientWidth)
    {
        var fs = parseFloat(textArea1.style.fontSize) - 1;
        textArea1.style.fontSize = fs + 'px';

        sizeText1.value = (fs | 0) + 'px';

        document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = ((parseInt(textArea1.style.fontSize))/textboxscale);
        sizeText1.value = ((parseInt(textArea1.style.fontSize))/textboxscale);
    }
}
textAreaChange();
```

Thanks in advance.
Davetoff

Right I have added the `if (fs>15)` to this code, but now it lock up when it gets to 15:

```
function textAreaChange(){
var fss = 15;
    var textArea1 = document.getElementById("textarea");
    var sizeText1 = document.getElementById("size_text");

    while (textArea1.scrollWidth > textArea1.clientWidth)
    {
        var fs = parseFloat(textArea1.style.fontSize) - 1;
if (fs >15){
        textArea1.style.fontSize = fs + 'px';

        sizeText1.value = (fs | 0) + 'px';

        document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = ((parseInt(textArea1.style.fontSize))/textboxscale);
        sizeText1.value = ((parseInt(textArea1.style.fontSize))/textboxscale);
    } else {
        textArea1.style.fontSize = fss + 'px';

        sizeText1.value = (fss | 0) + 'px';

        document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = fss + 'px';

}
}
}
```

Please help really appreciated spent a couple of days on this now and my head is beginning to hurt:

Thanks.

Davetoff

Comment: can't you just use CSS to change the font size? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4490427/526704

Answer (score 0):

After the line where you assign "fs", just add a statement to make sure that if fs is too small, you don't assign it to the textArea1 font size, something like:

```
if (fs > 7)  //only perform statements below if fs > 7
{
...
}
```

Comment: Still can't get this to work, I know it should work a treat but doesn't. Code below

Comment: var fs = parseFloat(textArea1.style.fontSize) - 1;
        if (fs>15){
textArea1.style.fontSize = fs + 'px';
sizeText1.value = (fs | 0) + 'px';
} else {
textArea1.style.fontSize = 15 'px';
sizeText1.value = 15 'px';
}

Answer (score 0):

Right found the problem, indeed the answer was to add the if statement, however I was being a fool as I had a scale factor in there that was causing all sorts of problems, also I've added a keycode in there to stop additional key inputs when the end of the text area is reached, updated code below:

```
function textAreaChange(){
var fss = <?=$min_text_size?>*textboxscale;
    var textArea1 = document.getElementById("textarea");
    var sizeText1 = document.getElementById("size_text");

   if (textArea1.scrollWidth > (textArea1.clientWidth))
    {
        var fs = parseFloat(textArea1.style.fontSize) - (2);
if (fs >(14*textboxscale)){
        textArea1.style.fontSize = (fs) + 'px'; //this is the textarea style

        document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = (parseInt(textArea1.style.fontSize)/textboxscale); //this is some text to show the user what size the text is

        sizeText1.value = ((parseInt(textArea1.style.fontSize))/textboxscale); //this is a slider I put to chage the text height manually (input range)
} else{
        textArea1.style.fontSize = (fss) + 'px';

        document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = fss/textboxscale;
        sizeText1.value = fss /textboxscale;

    if (event.keyCode == 8, 32) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
}
}
```

However the keycode 8,32 works well in IE but not in Firefox, any additional help would be really appreciated?

D